# React useEffect rendering more than once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm new in Hooks. I coded a project with `componentDidMount`.

Now I'm learning about hooks and rewriting this project with hooks. I want to fetch the data and print it on the console first.
However, it renders 3 times. It is probably because I used 2 `setState` in `useEffect`. However, in one of them I set the data to data array and in the other I keep the loading value for spinner control. How can I use `useEffect` like `componentDidMount` just one time to pull data and set my states?

When I write the console into `useEffect`, "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'data'." warning and returns an empty list.

Btw I deleted strictmode.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get("/data/data.json");
      setData(data);
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  console.log(data);
  return <div className="App">App</div>;
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: The `useEffect` is not running more than once, it's the component that is re-rendering. There's nothing inherently wrong with re-rendering, but in this case the process is (1) component renders (2) useEffect runs, call `fetchData` (3) `fetchData` calls `setData` (4) component renders 2nd time because `data` changed.

Comment: is this code working properly? how can i run it once?

Comment: It appears to be correct. Multiple calls to your `console.log` is not an error, that is expected.

Comment: You have two `data` variables (one from `useState` and one for you API call). That might be causing a conflict. I recommend changing the name of one.

Comment: &GalAbra i think you are confused just as the question owner... read the comments again..

Comment: It's a deafult behaviour of useEffect (react 18). It only happens in dev env . try removing strictmode to test it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think having the `data` variable twice might be causing a conflict with the linter. You can rename your data coming from your API call to prevent the warning: "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'data'."

Your component will re-render on each state update, but the `useEffect` will only run when your dependencies change. Since they aren't going to change, the API call only happens once.

To prove it, you can move the `console.log(result)` in your `useEffect` and see it only logs once. However, make sure you call it on your `result` and not `data`, because the state won't be updated until the next render after calling `setData`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const { data: result } = await axios.get("/data/data.json");
      setData(result);
      setLoading(false);
      console.log(result); // runs once
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [setData, setLoading]);

  console.log(data); // runs 3 times
  return <div className="App">App</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: why did you write "[setData, setLoading]" as parameter for useEffect? When I change the loading state again somewhere else, it will call useEffect again. I want useEffect works only once for fetching data from api or something else. Can you explain?

Comment: I added those because they are dependencies for your `useEffect` meaning you use those two variable in the `useEffect` body. The linter will usually complain if you don't put all variables that are in the `useEffect` body in the dependencies array. However, since those two functions will never change, they won't ever trigger a re-render. A change in loading won't cause the `useEffect` to be called again, the function `setLoading` is in the dependency array, not `loading`.

Answer (score 1):

The component re-renders normally after each state update.
Hence, in your example, it re-renders when the value of `data` is updated and again, when `loading` is updated.

Please check this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-bohr-l5hs0?file=/src/App.js) to examine how the renderings occur after each state change:

1. Initial render
2. After `loading` is set to `true`
3. After `data` is fetched and set
4. After `loading` is set to `false`